# When should you push variables in quotes in boolean conditions?

Tags: linux, bash

Are the following two boolean expressions the same?

```
if [ -n $1 ] ; then   
if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
```

And these two

```
if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
if [ "$?" == 0 ] ; then
```

If not - When should you put a variable in quotes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

put variables in quotes when there is any chance that the value may contain white spaces, or in general NOT be a continuous string of characters. So

as `$?` should always be something between 0 and 255, you don't need to quote that because it is a return value set after each sub-process returns. It is NOT possible to break that by assigning a string value directly, i.e.

```
$?=Is of course wrong and should be

 ?=Bad value assigment
```

because a user variable name must start with [A-Za-z_] , so don't do that ;-)

Whereas for $1, if a value is passed in like

```
myscript "arg1 with spaces"
```

the test

```
if [ -n $1 ] ; then
```

will blow up,

but the test

```
if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
```

will succeed.

IHTH

Comment: Thanks - I think I understand it a bit better now.  Is there a reason why putting quotes for `"$?"` causes the boolean to evaluate in an unintended fashion?  Like I understand why it would be useful to put `"$1"` in quotes, but when I put `"$?"` in quotes it doesn't work.

Comment: See edits. All good points below. +1 for everyone! I'm not sure what you mean that "$?" doesn't work. try `set -vx; true ; if [ $? = 0 ] ; then echo passed ; else echo failed ; fi ; false ;f [ $? = 0 ] ; then echo passed ; else echo failed ; fi ; set +vx` to see what is happening. Sub in various combos inside the `[ ... ]` and as a variant `[[ .... ]]` . Good luck to all.

Comment: @shelter: remember that `[ $? = 0 ]` is a textual comparison.  An arithmetic comparison would be `(( $? == 0 ))` (cold also be `[ $? -eq 0 ]`, but's that's horrible)

Answer (score 8):

Using the `[` command (yes, it's a command), you should nearly always use quotes. The exceptions are so rare I may not even go into them. For example,

```
set -- 'x -a -z b'
if [ -n $1 ]; then echo foo; fi
# … crickets
if [ -n "$1" ]; then echo foo; fi
foo
```

Bash also has the `[[` keyword (yes, it's a keyword), which is smart enough to know about expansions and avoid the traps of not quoting. (But it's still usually safe to quote within `[[` expressions.)

Since the `[` command is POSIX compliant and `[[` is a bashism, you decide when to use which.

As for your second example, if you're comparing something to a number, using `==` is a bashism. If you're writing for bash, use an arithmetic expression, such as

```
if (( $? == 0 )); then …
```

But if you're trying for POSIX compliance, write it

```
if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then …
```

Often, direct comparisons against `$?` are a red flag, since comparing the success/failure of a command is exactly what `if` does:

```
if somecommand; then …
```

is better than

```
somecommand
if (( $? == 0 )); then …
```

But if you do need to use it, `$?` is something of an exception, because it is guaranteed to only ever be a single-byte unsigned integer, so it's pretty safe to use unquoted, although it doesn't hurt to quote.

```
$ false; if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
f
$ true; if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
t
$ false; if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
f
$ true; if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
t
$ false; if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
f
$ true; if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
t
$ false; if [ "$?" == 0 ]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
f
$ true; if [ "$?" == 0 ]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
t
```

Comment: Actually when I quote `"$?"` the boolean expression evaluates differently than when I don't quote it...

Comment: @user784637 I don't know how to explain that. It doesn't seem possible, unless something is very wrong with your system or you're misinterpreting the results. I've posted a demonstration in my answer.

Comment: @user784637 well, `$?` isn't the number of arguments; it's the success/failure of the most recently-run command. You probably meant `$#`.

Comment: Even worse than your first example, try: `emptyvar=""; if [ -n $emptyvar ]; then echo "Apparently it's not empty"; fi`

Answer (score 4):

They are not always the same. If the variable in question is empty or contains whitespace, the `[` command (alias for `test`) can have too few or too many arguments.

In `bash`, you can use the builtin `[[ -n $1 ]]` condition construct that does not split the variable into words before evaluating the condition, which means no double quotes are needed.

Comment: Thanks choroba, I tried to delete the question I posed on askubuntu that you answered regarding this.

Comment: It's not strictly true that "does not expand the variable before evaluating the condition" -- the [bash manual says](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs): "Word splitting and filename expansion are not performed on the words between the ‘[[’ and ‘]]’; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution, process substitution, and quote removal are performed." -- the lack of word splitting is the key here.